# NTLMv2 requires extended security, When using Dexguard obfuscate in android

Tags: android, jcifs, dexguard

I had used **jcifs 1.3.17 jar** in my application (on libs folder).

My application works fine, before obfuscate my app by DEXGuard. After obfuscate my app, It gives the run-time  error like below.

```
NTLMv2 requires extended security (jcifs.smb.client.useExtendedSecurity must be true if jcifs.smb.lmCompatibility >= 3)
```

I am building using, ant release. like below

```
-verbose
-libraryjars /libs/jcifs 1.3.17 jar
```

Guide me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try to set these parameters for jcifs (i.e. in your web.xml if running in a servlet container):

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jcifs.smb.lmCompatibility</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jcifs.smb.client.useExtendedSecurity</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
```